# Content resolver not working on tablet device

Tags: java, android

I have a simple activity which shows a recyclerview of employees.
I also have two layout files for this activity

- activity_main.xml: includes a frame to MainFragment class
- activity_main.xml (sw600dp) includes a frame to MainFragment class

  ```
        Cursor employeeData = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
  ```

The line above is called in the **onCreateView** method inside my Fragment class. It returns all of my employees when executed on a phone emulator
But when i run it on a tablet emulator it returns a count of 0 (no records).

Does anyone have an idea how this problem can be solved or what is causing it?

Comment: What `ContentProvider` does `CONTENT_URI` point to? If it is your own... that is rather unusual in modern Android app development.

Comment: It is my own, this was required for an assignment

Comment: Then, presumably, your database (or whatever your `ContentProvider` is using for storage) is empty. Where is your data coming from?

Comment: Data is coming from a SQLite database, i find this very unusual since i can access the data on a phone emulator and not on a tablet emulator

Comment: "Data is coming from a SQLite database" -- then, presumably, your database is empty.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. The database is indeed empty because it is another device